# SoapUI. Export and Import properties to file by script

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I need to export and import properties from testcase(SoapUI) to file by java or groovy, anybody had met such task?

Manual option does not suit me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is any built-in API available for the same.

However, here are the scripts to import and export test case properties respectively.

**Import** a properties files to a test case. Groovy script follows:

```
/**
 * this method imports properties to a test case from a file.
 * @param context
 * @param filePath
 */
def importPropertiesToTestCase(def context,String filePath) {
    def  props = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File(filePath)
    //load the properties files into properties object
    props.load(propFile.newDataInputStream())
    //loop thru the properties and set them at test case level
    props.each {
        context.testCase.setPropertyValue(it.key, it.value.toString())
    }
}
//How to use above method. Make sure you have file with properties, change path if needed.
importPropertiesToTestCase(context, 'D:/Temp/testCase.properties')
```

**Export** Test Case properties to a file. Groovy Script follows:

```
/**
 * this method exports test case properties into a file.
 * @param context
 * @param filePath
 */
def exportTestCaseProperties(def context, String filePath) {
    def  props = new Properties()
    //Get all the property names of test cases
    def names = context.testCase.getPropertyNames()
    //loop thru names and set Properties object
    if (names) {
        names.each { name ->
            log.info "Set property ${name}"
            props.setProperty(name, context.testCase.getPropertyValue(name))
        }
        //Write properties object to a file
        def propFile = new File(filePath)
        props.store(propFile.newWriter(), null)
        log.info "Check the properties file: ${filePath}"
    } else {
        log.info "There does not seem to have any test case properties to write, check it."
    }
}
//How to use above method
exportTestCaseProperties(context, 'D:/Temp/testCase1.properties')
```

Comment: Glad to know that it is of useful.

Comment: Comment incorrectly passed in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716750/5292302) by [spartanhooah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2687836/spartanhooah) "when I tried your solution, SoapUI complains that  `No signature of method: java.util.Properties.store() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.BufferedWriter) values`:..."